# Merging PDFs with Apache PDFBox & inserting after section

Tags: apache, latex, pdf-generation, server-side, pdfbox

I need to merge multiple files together to create a single PDF somehow. Ideally, I could take PDFs as input and then mash them together without having to worry about formatting, so I'm thinking do that for the time being. Eventually, it would be nice if I could scan through the PDF for some specific metadata about a section in a PDF, and insert content after that section.

Essentially, something like the id attribute in html for PDFs is what I need (short of scanning the PDF text as that may change). Worst case scenario, I could use JSON as an interim format and create a PDF from the JSON, but I'd prefer not to format the PDF on the fly if I don't have to. JSON->LaTeX->PDF (or maybe just LaTeX->PDF) seems like what I might be looking at there, which seems like more pre-processing than is strictly needed.

Basically, is there any way to do this just via some hidden PDF metadata, or am I looking at scanning the document text for keywords?

**Footnote**:
I'm assuming I'm going to be given either a text file (converted to JSON) or a PDF as the initial input, but I definitely do want PDF output. Basically, just creating a PDF is simpler than requiring this be written in JSON.

Comment: When you write 'section' is that after a page or within a page?

Comment: It's within a page.